# Custom PowerShell Module importing due to nested modules

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell Module that will extend functionality of some existing PowerShell cmdlets to do some work-specific tasks for me.  For an example:

```
function Add-UserToSpecificGroup {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $DomainAdminCreds,
    )
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $(Get-ADGroup -Identity "Specific Group") -Members $Username -Credential $DomainAdminCreds -Server servername.domain  -Confirm:$false
}
```

This requires me to import the ActiveDirectory module, which I am doing in the PowerShell Module manifest as a nested module.  The only two important lines from the manifest are these:

```
NestedModules = @('ActiveDirectory')
FunctionsToExport = @('Add-UserToSpecificGroup')
```

However, now if I try to run any basic cmdlet from the ActiveDirectory module, e.g. `Get-ADUser`, instead of importing the ActiveDirectory module it imports my custom module.  Is there a way I can stop this from happening?  I would prefer the custom module to only be imported if I were calling a function that required it, not anything in the ActiveDirectory module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am using the wrong method.  The `RequiredModules` parameter in the manifest produces the expected result.